# Factor analysis with binary variables using Stata 13

Tags: stata, binary-data, confirmatory-factor

I am trying to do confirmatory factor analysis on data that is coded binary (`0` no, `1` yes). UCLA suggests using a tetrachoric correlation matrix, which,
however, assumes that binary variables reflect underlying continuous variables. Is there a way to relax this assumption and use logistic procedures
instead? I am using Stata Version 13. Could generalized SEM provide a solution?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your problem. Are you sure you don't want latent class analysis instead of CFA? Or are you trying to estimate a latent, continuous variable from several indicators that are truly dichotomous in nature? If the latter, that sounds like a job for item response theory...

Comment: Cross-posting of http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1884-cfa-with-binary-variables Neither forum forbids cross-postings, but it is polite to tell us. For example, the hint to think item response theory has already been made on Statalist.

Comment: Thank you, Nick Stauner and please apologize, Nick Cox, I did not know about cross-posting, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: And Nick Stauner, I am indeed looking at item response theory (-> see: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1884-cfa-with-binary-variables). IRT has helped me to specify my measurement model as part of the generalized SEM. In a further step, I wish to correlate my latent variable with another exogenous observed var., while controlling for other factors. Yet, trying to model this in gsem, Stata gives the following failure notice: "var2 does not identify a gaussian error or latent variable".
Does anyone have any advice what I could do about this?

Comment: You can do this with gsem (I believe), which is equivalent to IRT.